# Push forward of a vector bundle is a quotient

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, vector-bundles

Let $f\colon X\to Y$ be a (finite sheeted) cover of connected (nice) spaces, $V\to X$ a vector bundle over $X$, and $p\colon Z\to Y$ a (finite) regular cover of $Y$ which factors through $f$, i.e., $Y=Z/G$ for some (finite) group $G$. Then
$$
f_*(V)=\left(\bigoplus_{h\in \operatorname{Hom}(Z,X)}h^*(V)\right)\bigg/G,
$$
where $\operatorname{Hom}(Z,X)=\{h\colon Z\to X\mid fh=p\}$ and $G$ acts in the obvious way. What is this lemma called? (Apologies in advance for ag tag but maybe it's appropriate given that I don't really care about the category.)

Comment: How do you define $f_*(V)$?

Comment: It's just the direct image of V, so $f_*(V)_y=\oplus_{x\in f^{-1}(y)}V_x$.

Comment: Err, push forward, I guess.

Comment: if $f$ is regular cover as well (group $H$), the fibre prod. $X \times_Y Z$ is trivial $H$-cover over Z (since by assumption has a section over $Z$). It's then a disjoint union of copies of $Z$ indexed by the maps $h$ above, mapping as identity to $Z$ and by $h$ to $X$. In this case, the formula follows since pushing forward by $f$ and pulling back to $Z$ is the same thing as pulling back to $X \times_Y Z$ and pushing forward to $Z$ AND using that pullback under $Z \to Y$ is equivalence of sheaves on $Y$ with $G$-equivariant sheaves on $Z$ (with inverse=quotient / $G$ as in your formula).

Comment: I can do basic covering space theory, thanks.